# How does gradient give $g$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, potential, differentiation, calculus

How is
$$g=-\nabla V$$
where $V$ is gravitational potential and $g$ is acceleration due to gravity.
I am new to calculus.

Comment: Here V varies with distance from (0,0,0).

Comment: The gravitational force is a [conservative vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Definition) so it can be written as the gradient of a potential function.

Comment: As I am new to calculus could you please elaborate why I cannot just divide v by r=$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and instead $\nabla V to g$.

Comment: I believe OP is asking this having seen that given a spherically potential: $V(r) = -\frac{GM}{r}$, the gravitational field strength is $\frac{GM}{r^2}$ - OP, please note that this is just a special case of $\nabla V$ = $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}V(r) =\frac{GM}{r^2}$, the former formula does *not* hold for general $V$

Comment: are you aware how potential energy is defined for a general conservative force?

Comment: Ok now I understand.Yes I know I should have studied it a bit more before asking but .

Comment: Yes I knew that.

Answer (score 2):

Every conservative force (e.g. gravity) can be presented as a gradient of some scalar potential (let it be $-\nabla U$, because work of conservative force depends only on initial and final position,
$$
W_\mathrm{conservative} = \int\limits_{\mathbf{r}_1}^{\mathbf{r}_2} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} = \int\limits_{\mathbf{r}_1}^{\mathbf{r}_2}-(\nabla U)\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}  = -(U(\mathbf{r}_2)-U(\mathbf{r}_1)).
$$
If we define the change of potential energy as a $\Delta U = -W_\mathrm{conservative}$, then $U$ is the desired potential energy. Since $g = F/m$ and $V=U/m$ once finds the relation $g = -\nabla V$.

Comment: As I am new to calculus could you please elaborate why I cannot just divide v by r=$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ to get it?

Comment: Unfortunately, for the force  $\propto 1/r^2$ it works (more or less, because the sign is wrong) but when you consider other conservative forces, e.g. Hooke's Law $F=-kx$ what shall you do? Potential energy is then $-\int (-kx) dx = kx^2/2$

Answer (score 2):

This is really a **definition** of a potential function. The way a potential function works is that we want to conceive of the force as the result of the object trying to minimize its available energy. Hence we assign an energy to each point in space, which is what the potential field does, and the force experienced must tend to take it toward places of lower energy.

Hence the negative gradient, which gives the direction at which the energy decreases most readily.

Comment: "..object trying to minimize its available energy"  Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your mass M at the origin of an xyz system, then its gravitational potential (with zero at infinity) can be written as V = -GM$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{(-1/2)}$.  The gradient is (dV/dx)i + (dV/dy)j + (dV/dz)k.  In this case (dV/dx) = [-GM(-1/2)$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{(-3/2)}$][(2x)].  The y and z components are similar.  Adding these three gives the negative of the gradient as:  [-GM/($r^3$)][xi + yj + zk] which gives g (as a vector). Or,in polar coordinates: V = -GM$r^{-1}$  and the gradient is GM/$r^2$.